# Refresh browser after route change in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am learning react-router for client-side routing in my basic webpage. I want to know how to refresh the browser once immediately after the route changes.

Is there a way to refresh the browser after the route changes using react-router?
Please do comment for more clarity if needed.

Note: Please provide suggestions for scenarios where react-router v4 is not used and an older version of react-router is used. (Just curious...........XD)

Comment: Why would you need to refresh the browser?

Comment: Just wanted to know. As part of learning, I am generating random numbers in each component when it loads up. When I manually refresh the page, a new number shows up in the component. So, I thought how to automatically refresh the browser as the component loads up. I was just curious......

Comment: Its entirely possible to do all that using lifecycle methods and if you elaborate your use case with the code snippet, people might actually be able to help you better

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for programmatically updating react router and found the best anwser which covers all router versions.

hope you will find this useful

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31079244/8542218

to refresh the page you can simply pass '/' or your home(landing) page route.